# Interpreting chi-squared value returned by Excel 2010

Tags: chi-squared-test, excel, dice

I'm trying to assess whether the number of doubles (dice) being rolled by my opponents on a backgammon website are fair; to the naked eye they most definitely aren't but I need some science to back up my claims.

Using the CHISQ.TEST function in Excel 2010, I'm getting a value returned of 0.038.  What does this actually mean?

For background info, the source data is

Total dice rolls = 3962
1-1 = 114
2-2 = 116
3-3 = 107
4-4 = 125
5-5 = 134
6-6 = 131

Many thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Your six dice rolls does not sum to 3962 (I get 727). Can you clarify?

Comment: those dicerolls are his non-doubles. only the doubles are specified.

Comment: As per Sirius, total dice rolls = 3962, the doubles only are specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a good case for the [binomial test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test)

You'd expect $1/6$ of cases to be a double when you roll two dice.

I don't have excel in front of me, but judging from google searches it seems to have the  `binom.dist` function available for this.

You are observing 727 doubles out of the 3962 roll total.

The probability of this many should then be 1 minus this:

```
=BINOM.DIST( 727, 3962, 1/6, TRUE )
```

If excel is worth its salt, this should give: `0.9976782`. Your p-value then is `1 - this` (for a one-sided test), which is less than 0.05 and you shold reconsider ever playing with your friend again!

Comment: What's the significance of the 0.05 figure?

Comment: A p-value of 0.05 is deemed suffiient to reject your null hypothesis (which is that 1/6th of throws should be doubles in this case). It's an established norm, the history of which goes beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about excel, and what that returned value of 0.038 is. At least, excel documentation ought to tell you if it is meant as the observed chi-squared value, or a p-value.

But using R I get:

```r
N <- 3962
> doubles <- c(114, 116, 107, 125, 134, 131)
> str(chisq.test)
function (x, y = NULL, correct = TRUE, p = rep(1/length(x), length(x)), 
    rescale.p = FALSE, simulate.p.value = FALSE, B = 2000)  
> chisq.test(c(N-sum(doubles), doubles), p=c(5/6, rep(1/36, 6)))

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  c(N - sum(doubles), doubles)
X-squared = 13.118, df = 6, p-value = 0.0412
```

so some evidence of non-uniformity. It is usefull to look at the individual cell values (contributions to the chi-squared statistic):

```r
 obs <- c(N-sum(doubles), doubles)
 names(obs) <- c("offdiag", "1-1", "2-2", "3-3", "4-4", "5-5", "6-6")
 p <- c(5/6, rep(1/36, 6))
 E <- N*p
 (obs-E)^2 / E
  offdiag       1-1       2-2       3-3       4-4       5-5       6-6 
1.3461215 0.1413708 0.3210780 0.0848337 2.0293062 5.2095182 3.9858938
```

so the largest contributions to chi-squared comes from 5-5 and 6-6. The test in the answer by @Sirius only considers doubles as a group, not individually, in difference from this chi-squared test that considers the doubles individually.